# How to Break Long Equation which Exceed Page Width

Tags: equations

Excuse me . . .

How do I write long mathematical formulas in \LaTeX so that formulas that exceed the width of the page are automatically cut off and fall to the next line without typing double backslash ?

Thank you very much for the answer . . .

Comment: You always have to do your own manual breaking (and it is not recommended to use `breqn` as it has several issues). For displayed formulas there are no 100% accurate procedure as to here is where you need to break the formula, this needs experience. And have to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. Here you have some of them:

- You can use the `\begin{split}` environment. The `\begin{split}` environment allows you to split a long formula into multiple lines. The formula will be automatically broken at the nearest operator or delimiter.

For example, the following code will create a long formula that is split into two lines:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x) &= x^2 + 2x + 1 \\
&= (x + 1)^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Ouput:

```
f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1
= (x + 1)^2
```

- Using the `\begin{multline}` environment, which is similar to the \begin{split} environment, but it allows you to control the breaking of the formula more precisely.

Here is an example:

```
\begin{multline}
f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1 \\
&= (x + 1)(x + 1) \\
&= x^2 + 2x + 1
\end{multline}
```

Output:

```
f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1
= (x + 1)(x + 1)
= x^2 + 2x + 1
```

I hope it helps!